# Getting SSL handshake error

Tags: ssl, weblogic

I am consuming third party web service in my application. It has https url which requires handshake. I am using Weblogic application Server and I want to configure the certificate in my server.

Can anyone please provide me steps to configure that certificate?

Also What is Identity and Trust on Weblogic Console?

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by using keytool command provided in Jdk bin folder.

I just went to demotrust.jks and imported the third party certificate in it and it worked for me.

I used below command.

```
${ORACLE_HOME}/product/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_20-R28.1.0-4.0.1/bin/keytool -import -alias [AliasForYourCertificate]  -keystore ${ORACLE_HOME}/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/DemoTrust.jks -file /home/oracle/[YourCertFile].crt
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the cacerts file for the JVM used by WebLogic. Using the WebLogic console, select the server. Then use the Configuration > Keystores tab to find the cacerts file location labeled Java Standard Trust Keystore on this page.

You will want to import the certificate from the web service into this cacerts file. If you are a Windows user, I use a free tool called Keystore Explorer (http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/). This application allows to directly import the certificate using the URL. Do this by opening your cacerts file in KeyStore Explorer then use the Examine SSL option to import the certificate.